# Query on UNION view is very slow when queried with ORDER BY clause on an indexed column, with LIMIT specified

Tags: sql, postgresql

- I have two tables of identical structure in postgresql,
  `archived_orders` and `orders`.
- `archived_orders` has about 300 million records, and `orders` table
  has about 30 million
- Both tables have indexes on column `received_time`.
- I have a view `all_orders` on these two tables, created with below sql:

  `CREATE VIEW all_orders AS SELECT * FROM archived_orders UNION SELECT * from orders;`
- I do the below query on the view.

  `SELECT * FROM all_orders WHERE received_time >= '2023-02-10 00:00:00' order by received_time LIMIT 500;`

The query takes a really long time to finish. But I can get the result of the above query in less than a second by executing it separately on two tables, manually sorting it by `received_time` and taking the first 500 records. The queries I do separately is as below:

```
SELECT * FROM archived_orders WHERE received_time >= '2023-02-10 00:00:00' order by received_time LIMIT 500;

SELECT * FROM orders WHERE received_time >= '2023-02-10 00:00:00' order by received_time LIMIT 500;
```

Why is the query on the view really slow? Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: Please show the actual fast query. Your description of it is rather vague.

Comment: Why is this a UNION rather than UNION ALL?

Comment: @jjanes updated the question with two separate queries.

Comment: @jjanes I am not sure why it is UNION. It was already there when I got into this issue. Would it be any help if I change it to UNION ALL?

Comment: @LahiruChandima: Isn't that something you could answer yourself by just changing it to UNION ALL and executing it?

Comment: @KenWhite, yes, I was on it. It actually did the trick. Thanks.